# No privacy options in Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: gnome, privacy

Running Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 updated till date.

In System Settings, there is no 'Privacy' Settings option. In the Help for system settings, it does mention 'Privacy' settings (like what appears on the lock screen, etc.)

Am I missing something? How do I get the privacy options?

Comment: @przemo Linux Mint does *not* use `gnome-control-center`, but its own. Besides, this is off topic here as LM is not an official derivate of Ubuntu.

Comment: I know that, I was just concerned about privacy issues in all linux distros in general, but you're right, it was off topic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the **gnome-control-center** because after intallation that one nothing changed. Perhaps, topicstarter uninstalled **"Zeitgeist"** (**"Activities and Privacy Manager Tool"** in **"Ubuntu Applications Center"**), - that's why it disappeared from **"System Settings"**. When you reinstall it, it wiil appear in **"System Settings"** again.